# Is there any way in flutter onesignal that indicates the notification was opened when in background or foreground?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, onesignal

I've been looking for a way to get some sort of a enum state indicates whether the notification was opened when the app is killed (in background) or the app is running (in foreground).

Any solutions come in mind?